# How to link a user account to app store account IAP?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I want to attach my app user account to one app store account in in-app purchase i.e, in my app at the signup user have to purchase a plan via in-app purchase, so i want that when user go on another device then to purchase another plan he should purchase by same app store account that he used at signup.

Comment: If the user goes to another device then they wouldn't need to purchase another plan. They can just restore their purchase using the same App Store account. You could map the receipt details to the user account on your server to prevent the user from using the same App Store purchase with different accounts on your server.

Comment: @Paulw11 i want that the user of my app (user@myapp.com) first time purchase product A with ab@xyz.com app store id and then on another device same user (user@myapp.com) tries to purchase product B with ac@xyz.com app store id, so in this case i want to show error that user has to use ab@xyz.com app store id to make transaction. I have already seen this in some iOS apps.

Comment: I guess you could get the receipt on the second device and get your server to verify that the original purchase id matches the one you saw from the first device.  If it doesn't then they are probably logged into a different App Store account, but there is no direct way that you can get the user's Apple ID directly.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your support

Answer (score -1):

Purchasing from one account and then using another for in-app purchase (IAP) isn't currently possible.

Since each application is digitally signed when you download it from the App Store - you are tied to using the same account for in-app purchases as for the initial purchase.

If it is a free app, you could back up the device to iCloud, delete the app, re-purchase the app under the correct account and then restore the device from the backup. If you are not worried about saving game state, you can skip the backup and the restore steps.

If the app is not free, then you are faced with deciding to buy the in-app purchase from the original account or re-buying the app on the correct account.